# There is no changing When I used to the integer type

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a web service for my Android app. When I used to it is an integer type and telefon_number, dogum_tarihi string type, They are work. But I want to use that telefon_number, dogum_tarihi are integers. İf I use to like that, there is no changing in my PHPMyAdmin. I thought long time. And I decided. İt is may related with PHPMyAdmin values type.

How can I fix  it?

My sqli code :

```
    <?php
    include ("ayar.php");

    $id = $_POST["id"];

    $telefon_number = $_POST["telefon_number"];
    $dogum_tarihi = $_POST["dogum_tarihi"];
    $sehir = $_POST["sehir"];
    $ilce = $_POST["ilce"];


$sql = mysqli_query($connect , "UPDATE kullanici SET  ilce='$ilce'   ,sehir='$sehir',
dogum_tarihi ='$dogum_tarihi' , telefon_number = '$telefon_number'  WHERE id={$id}");


    if ($sql) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: ";
    }


    ?>
```

When I tested this code. It gives me always "Record updated successfully".

My values and its types in PHPMyAdmin:

[image]

Comment: do you mean to change the data type of table field?

Comment: No. I want to It works. And I found my error where is . By the way I have never thought  "change the data type of table field?". I will try.

Comment: Duke. I did your advise now. And it works. Thank you. But I have question now. Why I used to intiger in dogum_tarihi and telefon_number , It does not work ? And If It does not work in intiger. Why id is working ?

Comment: i dont know, maybe because mysqli_query driver only accept string to string and integer to string. i think you muse use a php framework like laravel to easier coding.

Comment: I searched your advise. Thanks your advice. But I am using .hostinger.web.tr. İs it working there. Because lavarel"s codes are different. ( I am begginner in php coding.)

Comment: ok, good luck and keep learning.

Comment: I asked an question to you. Lavarel php framework"s codes are working on hostinger.web.tr ????  By the way ; gives the answer and take your reputation points " change the data type of table field". is true.

Comment: yes it work, but with free package you dont have enough space for laravel file. if you still beginner i think you can buy cheap hosting or try heroku.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the data type of telefon_number and dogum_tarihi.